# ConcurrentMap inconsistencies

Tags: java

The JavaDoc for ConcurrentMap - putIfAbsent says:

```
  /**
    * If the specified key is not already associated
    * with a value, associate it with the given value.
    * This is equivalent to
    *
    * if (!map.containsKey(key))
    *     return map.put(key, value);
    * else
    *    return map.get(key);
    *  
    * except that the action is performed atomically.
    */
```

But putIfAbsent (from ConcurrentMap) and put (from Map) return both the previous value (or null when there is no previous value). Therefore in the example, when the map does not contain the key, null is returned. Is this the correct intent of the code? Wouldn't it be better to return "value" instead?

Comment: You already have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the API was designed this way so you can distinguish between the case that there was no previous mapping (and the update succeeded) and that a former mapping was present but mapped to exactly the same `value`.

It doesn’t help to ask whether this is more practical than to get the new value instead. I stumbled across this behavior some times as well. But the API is there since Java 5, specified this way, and won’t be changed.

As a side note, Java 8’s [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) will behave more like you expected by returning the computed value if no previous mapping existed.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to show that

if (!map.containsKey(key)) return map.put(key, value);

always returns false

Comment: Map.computeIfAbsent is great, because you always hand over a function, which only executes expensive operations when necessary.

Comment: Right, `Map.computeIfAbsent` is what I’ve missed since the very first version of `ConcurrentMap`…

Answer (score 0):

You have the new value already (or should). There's no reason to return what you just inserted.

```
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ...
    String newVal = "someString";
    String old = map.putIfAbsent(1, newVal);
    if(old == null){
        //no previous mapping
    }
```